# Find unique set of identifiers/groups among several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, igraph

I have data with two (potentially more) columns of identifiers (typically long strings). These differ sometimes, are mistyped, or change over time. I want to identify unique subjects in the data. This requires identifying groups of cases which are connected via their ids at some level.

An example

```
df <- data.frame(ida = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
                 idb = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 7),
                 trueid = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id3"))
```

```
> df
  ida idb trueid
1   A   1    id1
2   B   1    id1
3   C   3    id2
4   C   4    id2
5   D   4    id2
6   E   7    id3
```

Identifiers for `id1` are `"A", "B", 1`, for `id2` `"C", "D", 3, 4` and for `id3` `"E", 7`.

I don't know `trueid` but need to find it using the information from columns `ida` and `idb`.

The solution needs to scale to millions of observations with tens of thousands of unique ids. I am already using `data.table`.

**Extension**: There is another scenario where there are more than two columns, and some columns might be informative for others, i.e. have the same identifiers. I do not know which columns are informative for which. I think type can be disregarded though, all columns are strings or can safely be converted.

Another example for this:

```
df <- data.frame(ida = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
                 idb = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "7"),
                 idc = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                 idd = c("1", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                 trueid = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2"))
```

```
> df
  ida idb idc idd trueid
1   A   1   1   1    id1
2   B   2   1   A    id1
3   C   3   2   2    id1
4   C   4   3   3    id1
5   D   4   4   4    id1
6   E   7   5   5    id2
```

**Edit:** As a commenter pointed out, this is essentially the clique problem of finding complete subgraphs in a graph. After reading a bit more, I understand this issue can be solved with `library(igraph)`. I am leaving the question open as I would prefer a solution that relies on `base`, `data.table` or `dplyr`. I cannot easily install packages on the server I am using, installing `igraph` involves dealing with a lot of red tape and delays.

**Edit2:** For anybody reading this and facing a similar problem: `zx8754`'s answer using igraph is considerably (several orders of magnitude) faster on larger (simulated) data with more groups. If you have the chance to use `igraph`, do so.

Comment: What is the rule to consider a case as unique ID?

Comment: A case that is linked to any other case via some id. I rephrased the question a bit. In the first case, identifiers for `id1` are `"A", "B", "1"`, for `id2` `"C", "D", 3, 4` and for `id3` `"E", 7`.

Comment: This sounds like a network analysis problem of identifying "cliques," where an edge exists between every node with at least one common variable, and each `trueid` is a "complete subgraphs" where the nodes can be connected through a finite number of steps.

Comment: Yes, it is essentially that. I am looking for a solution that does not rely on igraph or a more specific package.

Comment: Why not igraph?

Comment: Practical reasons. There is a lot of overhead associated with getting additional CRAN packages installed at my institution unfortunately - I've been through it once and would like to avoid it. The recursive solution using `data.table` works fine, although it is slower on larger simulated data. I'll give it a try on the actual data, if the cost penalty is too high, I'll try to get `igraph` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive approach using `data.table`:

```
#convert into a long format for easier processing
mDT <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.var="rn", variable.name="V", value.name="ID")[,
    tid := NA_integer_]

#the recursive function
link <- function(ids, label) {
    #identify the rows in DT containing ids and extract the IDs
    newids <- mDT[mDT[.(ID=ids), on=.(ID), .(rn=rn)], on=.(rn), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
        unique(ID)]

    #update those rows to the same group
    mDT[mDT[.(ID=ids), on=.(ID), .(rn=rn)], on=.(rn), tid := label]

    if (length(setdiff(newids, ids)) > 0L) {
        #call the recursive function if there are new ids
        link(newids, label)
    }
}

#get the first id that is not labelled yet
id <- mDT[is.na(tid), ID[1L]]
grp <- 1L
while(!is.na(id)) {
    #use recursive function to link them up
    link(id, grp)

    #repeat for next id that is not part of any group yet
    id <- mDT[is.na(tid), ID[1L]]
    grp <- grp + 1L
}

#update original DT with tid
DT[mDT, on=.(rn), tid := tid]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ida = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
    idb = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "7"),
    idc = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    idd = c("1", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this type of recursive solution was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Using *igraph*:

```
# example input, I removed "trueid" column
df <- data.frame(ida = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
                 idb = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "7"),
                 idc = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                 idd = c("1", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
#trueid = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2")

library(igraph)

# set up connections
# Improved version suggested by @thelatemail in the comments
x <- cbind(df[ 1 ], unlist(df[ -1 ]))

# original clumsy version (do not use)
# x <- unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:(ncol(df) - 1), function(i) setNames(df[, c(i, i + 1) ], c("from", "to")))))

# convert to graph object
g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)        

# plot if you wish to visualise
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
# this is the solution, add membership ids to original input dataframe
merge(df, data.frame(grp = clusters(g)$membership),
      by.x = "ida", by.y = 0)
#   ida idb idc idd grp
# 1   A   1   1   1   1
# 2   B   2   1   A   1
# 3   C   3   2   2   1
# 4   C   4   3   3   1
# 5   D   4   4   4   1
# 6   E   7   5   5   2
```

Comment: Alternative way to get `x` - `do.call(rbind, Map(cbind.data.frame, x=df[1:3], y=df[2:4]))`

Comment: Although given that this is just connection based it doesn't have to be reduced this much I don't think - even `x <- cbind(df[1], unlist(df[-1]))` should do it.

Comment: @thelatemail Agree, that ‘do.call’ bit was bad, just wanted to post something that works. If you don’t mind, I will edit with your suggestions.

Comment: Go for it - you owe me a virtual beer ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail edited, [cheers!](https://asciiart.website/index.php?art=food%20and%20drink/beer)