# Group rows if the value of a column appears in the other column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe that I want to group based on the values in a column.

The trick is though there are some rows that need be merged if the values have already appeared in a column that I am grouping by.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R4", "R5", "R5", "R5"),
                 col2 = c("R10", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R9"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df, FUN = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", "))

> df
  col1 col2
1   R1  R10
2   R2   R4
3   R2   R5
4   R2   R6
5   R2   R7
6   R4   R5
7   R5   R6
8   R5   R7
9   R5   R9

> df2
  col1           col2
1   R1            R10
2   R2 R4, R5, R6, R7
3   R4             R5
4   R5     R6, R7, R9
```

R10 will be in group R1 (row 1)

R4, R5, R6 and R7 will be in group R2 (rows 2 to 5)
R5 will be in group R4 (row 6)

R6, R7 and R9 will be in group R5 (rows: 7 to 9)

But R4 and R5 are already in R2 so this will stay in R2.
For R9 which is originally assigned to R5, needs to be grouped in to R2.

So the desired outcome will be:

```
> df3
  col1               col2
1   R1                R10
2   R2 R4, R5, R6, R7, R9
```

OR preferably:

```
1 col1 col2
2   R1  R10
3   R2   R4
4   R2   R5
5   R2   R6
6   R2   R7
7   R2   R9
```

Comment: `For R9 which is originally assigned to R5, needs to be grouped in to R2.` why? How?

Comment: Because R5 is included in R2. If you look at `df2` `col2`  R5 is mapped to R2.

Comment: Check out the *igraph* package - this is a clustering problem essentially if you can be flexible with your output. E.g.: `library(igraph); g <- graph.data.frame(df); clusters(g)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548395/find-unique-set-of-identifiers-groups-among-several-columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079559/make-a-group-indices-based-on-several-columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740990/fast-way-to-group-variables-based-on-direct-and-indirect-similarities-in-multipl

Comment: Wow, `igraph` package is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to `replace` the values based on the `intersect`ing elements and then do the `aggregate`

```
i1 <- df$col1 %in% df$col2
df$col1[i1] <- df$col1[match(df$col1[inds], df$col2)]
aggregate(col2 ~ col1, unique(df), FUN = toString)
#   col1               col2
#1   R1                R10
#2   R2 R4, R5, R6, R7, R9
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(col1 = case_when(col1 %in%  intersect(col1, col2) ~ "R2", 
                   TRUE ~ col1)) %>% 
    distinct %>% 
    summarise(col2 = toString(col2))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  col1  col2              
#  <chr> <chr>             
#1 R1    R10               
#2 R2    R4, R5, R6, R7, R9
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. In the actual dataset, I have more rows and more groups to be defined so I prefer not to hardcode `R2` if possible. Would there be a way to replace this line?

Comment: Thanks, this works on this example - in the actual dataset I've got, this still generates few overlapping groups but I think I can work from here.

Answer (score 1):

One option with base R can be

```
inds <- df$col1 %in% df$col2
df$col1[inds] <- df$col1[match(df$col1[inds], df$col2)]
```

and then we can take only `unique` values of dataframe

```
unique(df)

#  col1 col2
#1   R1  R10
#2   R2   R4
#3   R2   R5
#4   R2   R6
#5   R2   R7
#9   R2   R9
```

Or if you want comma-separated string

```
aggregate(col2 ~ col1, unique(df), toString)

#  col1               col2
#1   R1                R10
#2   R2 R4, R5, R6, R7, R9
```